# Override virtual property in C# using Visual Studio 2013 uml

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, uml, overriding, virtual

I have below property in the base class A, I want override it in derived class B using UML class diagram in Visual Studio 2013:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual string X
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

Override like this:

```
public class B : A
{
    public override string X
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

I generated code of model, but there is no override keyword in derived class B

Generated code:

```
public class B : A
{
    public string X
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

Comment: what is your question ??

Comment: In Model i set override for property x in class B but there is no override keyword in generated code?

Comment: because it does not know your intention, what you want to do with your class

Comment: @viveknuna I think Fouad wants to generate override keyword for overridden property in derived class,  that property in UML model after generating C# codes.

Comment: So, where is the UML-part of this question?

Answer (score 1):

Your attribute `X` in subclass `B` should have a `{redefines X}` constraint. It will be an information that the new X changes the inherited one.

While theoretically you can indicate that your attribute is inherited from a superclass with `^` mark, but you can't assume anything if it's missing. Redefines leaves no doubt.
I'm talking from UML perspective only. I know neither if Visual Studio supports this nor where to look for it.